# bean initialization- I am getting AssertionError:Not yet implemented

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

```
public class Etest {

    static Empserviceinter empservice;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Successfully bean initiated");
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("niit.Project");
        context.refresh();
        System.out.println("Bean Initialization");
        empservice = (Empserviceinter) context.getBean("empservice");
        System.out.println("Successfully bean initiated");
    }
}
```

Result displayed in console:

> Successfully bean initiated
>
> Bean Initialization

Comment: Can you show the test where you have an assertion error?

Comment: Why don't you use JUnit spring integration `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Comment: at this line i am getting assertion error
empservice = (Empserviceinter) context.getBean("empservice");

Comment: use `getBean("empservice", Empserviceinter.class)` instead of what you have now. Also please specify  which versions you are using and as mentioned before you should be using the Spring test context framework instead of wrapping your own. Finally please add the stacktrace to your question as that contains valuable information.